# Changing JNDI in tomcat at login time

Tags: java, tomcat

I am working on a jsp project in which login form contains three fileds as customer name , user name and password. In this case my mysql database name same as user inputted customer name. In tomcat/conf server.xml file contains JNDI info as below

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
Resource name="jdbc/TestDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
  factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
           maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
           username="root" password="root" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
           url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/customer1"/>
```

and tomcat/conf context.xml file contain below code

```
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/TestDB"
              global="jdbc/TestDB"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

My problem is that when customer login with different name then I want to update my server.xml file url like `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/customerXXX`? I have tried using tomcat PoolProperties but it didn't works, how I will change or update server.xml info or there other any ways I can achieve this.

Comment: And any other customer that was already logged in will then also automatically use that other database, since you're using the same datasource for all of them.

Comment: Each customer should use it's own datasource.

Comment: You're looking at this problem the wrong way. Leaving aside the desirability of a database per customer, which is dubious, the resource has to be session-scoped, rather than application-scoped, let alone global, for this to work at all.

Comment: Indeed. The real requirement here is to (dynamically) have a datasource per customer, which basically means you're not going to let Tomcat manage the datasources but the application itself will have to create them and manage them. But it is dubious to really want this; I'd rather have one datasource and one database in which the tables have a column that identifies them as belonging to a certain customer.

Comment: @Gimby Thanks for reply according to your suggestion I was changed my DB structures like one DB and differentiate customer adding one extra column and it work fine :)